# Mysql query to get count result and group by

Tags: mysql, database, count, group-by

I've got three tables with different records for users,

```
User

username |        realname   |         date
evn-az-3ju           john      11/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
jwyvm_rdyt           steve      12/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
bsMIAtWkhi           mahesh      01/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
zrObzh4um0           santa      01/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
WyVm_rDYt           grolsch      11/2012 03:09:40 p.m.

offline

username |       messageID |    message
jwyvm_rdyt           54      <message to="jwyvm_rdyt" id="t4Wa4-291" type="chat" from="evn-az-3ju"><body>test1</body><thread>1a327531-5a1c-4d6b-8b66-1209cdabb77d</thread></message>
jwyvm_rdyt           78      <message to="jwyvm_rdyt" id="t4Wa4-290" type="chat" from="evn-az-3ju"><body>Happy birthday</body><thread>1a327531-5a1c-4d6b-8b66-1209cdabb77d</thread></message>
evn-az-3ju           89      <message to="evn-az-3ju" id="t4Wa4-290" type="chat" from="evn-az-3ju"><body>Happy birthday</body><thread>1a327531-5a1c-4d6b-8b66-1209cdabb77d</thread></message>
zrObzh4um0           98      <message to="zrObzh4um0" id="t4Wa4-290" type="chat" from="evn-az-3ju"><body>Happy birthday</body><thread>1a327531-5a1c-4d6b-8b66-1209cdabb77d</thread></message>
WyVm_rDYt           45      <message to="WyVm_rDYt" id="t4Wa4-290" type="chat" from="evn-az-3ju"><body>Happy birthday</body><thread>1a327531-5a1c-4d6b-8b66-1209cdabb77d</thread></message>

roster

username |             jid       |     date
jwyvm_rdyt           evn-az-3ju      11/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
jwyvm_rdyt           zrObzh4um0      12/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
jwyvm_rdyt           bsMIAtWkhi      01/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
zrObzh4um0           WyVm_rDYt      01/2013 03:09:40 p.m.
WyVm_rDYt           zrObzh4um0      11/2012 03:09:40 p.m.
```

These are the tables from which i want result set like this,

```
 username |             realname       |     count
evn-az-3ju           john                     2
zrObzh4um0           santa                    0
bsMIAtWkhi           mahesh                   0
```

I want to know all the roster jid which username 'jwyvm_rdyt' has along with their realname and count of message if that message contains any roster jid in that. Like 'evn-az-3ju' is in message 54 and 78, so count 2 for that roster jid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: General advice: _Please_ normalize the data in your `offline` table.  As it stands now, we would have to find a way to extract the to and from parties in a message, and this could probably only be done via a custom MySQL function.

Comment: You may try to interpret the message field as xml and use the `ExtractValue()` function to get a value out of the xml. However, it is not clear to me what you are really after.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for replying back.. sorry i can't normalize the database. I'm using third party database i can't make any changes in the database structure.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for your reply.. it tried something like this `SELECT R.* FROM ofRoster R
JOIN ofOffline O ON R.jid =(ExtractValue(O.stanza, '//message/@from'))
WHERE R.username LIKE 'jWyVm_rDYt' GROUP BY R.jid` but it's not correct.

Comment: @Shadow it gives me no result.

Comment: Have you tested what `ExtractValue(O.stanza, '//message/@from')` returns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124025/discussion-between-user3588408-and-shadow).

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.jid as username,c.realname,COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(o.message), ''))  as count from  (select r.`jid`,u.realname from roster r join User u on r.jid=u.username  where r.username='jwyvm_rdyt' ) c  left  join offline o on o.message  like CONCAT('%', c.jid, '%') and o.username='jwyvm_rdyt' group by jid
```